# tabbar.el (v.2.0) -- organize buffers by tab groups associated with frames

Tags: emacs

Is it possible to have tabbar.el display buffers arbitrarily assigned to a given frame, but not organized by group?

If so, what would be the init.el configuration snippet?

The default configuration is grouping all buffers in all frames together and it is difficult to visually determine what buffer is associated with what frame.

Example:

```
Frame #1:
   *Messages*
   *scratch*
   buffer_three.txt
   buffer.four.tex

Frame #2:
    buffer_five.html
    buffer_six.cvs
```

I have been experimenting with `frame-cmds.el` and `frame-fns.el`, which gives the ability to rename the frame.  I have tried `frame-bufs.el`, but that one gives me some error messages.

Here is an example of four (4) frames, with arbitrary tabs associated with different frames.

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/frames.png))</sub>

Comment: How are buffers associated with a particular frame?

Comment: I'm looking for the ability to create my own arbitrary frames and put miscellaneous files of different types of modes.  Buffers would be assigned to the active frame (with focus).  If I'm working with Frame # 2, then any file that is opened or created would be assigned as a buffer to Frame # 2.  If I create a Frame # 3, then the buffer for that new frame would be assigned to Frame # 3 and be invisible when working on any of the other frames.  The examples I have seen organize buffers by groups rather than by frames.

Comment: Another example would be thinking of each Frame as a separate project.  Frame # 1 would be all files associated with Client # A (an arbitrary variety of text and tex files).  Frame # 2 would be for Client # B -- the files in each Frame / project might have the same names, but be saved to different directories -- e.g., 1add.txt and o_04_27_2013.tex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabs can be grouped by frame using the following code snippet with `tabbar.el` and the frame-bufs library written by Alp Aker:  https://github.com/alpaker/Frame-Bufs

```
(defun my-buffer-groups ()
"Doc-string."
  (list
    (cond
      ((memq (current-buffer) (frame-bufs-buffer-list (selected-frame)))
        "A")
      (t
        "N") )))

(setq 'tabbar-buffer-groups-function 'my-buffer-groups)
```